# How to prevent mail sent from Mutt from winding up in junk folders?

Tags: email, smtp, mutt

I have mutt configured to send/receive mail on behalf of an email address on a domain that I own (i.e., not a gmail, yahoo or other major domain). I'm attempting to set up a notification system to send brief emails to clients. Outgoing mail goes through an SMTP server with TLS.

However, in my testing so far, every single email I've sent to myself ends up in my junk email. This only happens with mutt; using my mail client on my phone, the same message correctly goes to the inbox. What would be causing this and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: That depends on your spamfilter. We may be able to spot some common problems if you show us the full header of a mail that gets spamfiltered and one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After toying with it a little more, I realized I had misconfigured my mailbox folders in `.muttrc`:

What I had (sent mail, but it went to junk):

```
set folder="imaps://customers.freehosting.com"
set spoolfile=$folder
set postponed="INBOX.Drafts"
set record="INBOX.Sent"
```

What I changed it to (now works):

```
set folder="imaps://customers.freehosting.com/INBOX"
set spoolfile=$folder
set postponed="=Drafts"
set record= "=Sent"
```